# Can I enter a Schengen country on the last day of my TRP?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen

I am from India. Currently I am living in a Schengen country 'X'. I have a TRP of this Schengen country which will expire after 1 day. Can I go to another Schengen country "Y" by flight on the last day of my TRP? Will there be any problem?

(TRP = 'Temporary Residence Permit' card) ...

Comment: What is a 'TRP'?

Comment: Temporary Residence Permit

Comment: Then yes, a D-Visa can be used until the last day of validity within the Schengen Area.

Comment: Will they find it suspicious that I am going to another Schengen country on the "last day" of my residence permit? (I am a Non-EU )

Comment: Only if you can't prove that you will be leaving on the same day. In general there won't be a control when entering the country Y. Checking will be done when leaving the Schengen Area. If you have a onward flight for the same day, there should be no problem. You must leave before the D-Visa expires.

Comment: @MarkJohnson a residence permit card is not a D visa, however similar they may be.

Comment: Did you apply to renew the residence permit?